# SQL server 2014 error with openrowset bulk and large text field

Tags: sql-server

I have a csv file (200.000 rows) with about 20 columns. One of the columns can contain a large amount of text data.

I try to read the csv with openrowset bulk and I use a format file. The large text column has varbinary (max) in the format file.

This is the command I use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'F:\Source.csv', FORMATFILE='F:\Source.fmt', 
                ERRORFILE = 'F:\Bulk_log.txt', FIRSTROW = 2) as t1
```

On one of the rows I get the following error:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 119426, column 4. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

When I look at the row causing the problem, the large text field has 69.339 bytes of data.

With the errorfile option then it shows the problem starts at 66.367 bytes.

Is there a limitation with openrowset and bulk on the maximum bytes it can read from large fields?

The weird thing is; when I copy the row causing the problem to a separate csv file containing the single problem row, everything works fine.....

I also tried to read the data with SSIS, and there everything works fine as well.
But I would like to stick to 'basic' SQL server (2014) and not move my load method to SSIS.

How can I solve this problem?